# Timer application using GTK

Tags: c, linux, gtk

## Purpose

The code is for a timer with a starting time of 25 minutes. The goal is to have a very simple pomodoro application with Start, Pause and Reset. Also you can tick a box to make the UI stay in front of the desktop so you always have the timer in front of your eyes.

## Hierarchy

```
main.c
  /src
    structures.h
    /features
      timer.c
      timer.h
    /frontend
      frontend.c
      frontend.h
      style.css
      view.glade
    /signals
      options.c
      options.h
      timer_buttons.c
      timer_buttons.h
```

## Code

### main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "src/structures.h"
#include "src/signals/options.c"
#include "src/signals/timer_buttons.c"
#include "src/frontend/frontend.c"
#include "src/features/timer.c"

int
main (int argc,
      char **argv)
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    struct TimerUI timerUi;
    bool success;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();

    // set up user interface
    success = init_view(builder);
    if (!success)
        return 1;

    // get and set up window
    window = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
    timerUi.window = GTK_WINDOW(window);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Pomodoro Timer");

    // connect signals to builder
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, &timerUi);

    // timer
    init_timer(builder, &timerUi);

    // style
    success = init_style(&timerUi);
    if (!success)
        return 1;

    // start
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

### **src/structures.h**

```
#ifndef STRUCTURES_H_INCLUDED
#define STRUCTURES_H_INCLUDED

struct TimerUI
{
    GtkWindow *window;

    GtkLabel *label;

    int hours;
    int seconds;

    int timerReference;
};

#endif // STRUCTURES_H_INCLUDED
```

### **src/features/timer.c**

```
#include "timer.h"
#include "../structures.h"

void
init_timer(GtkBuilder *builder,
           struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    // ui
    timerUi->label = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "timer"));

    // timer callback reference
    timerUi->timerReference = 0;

    // reset
    reset_timer(timerUi);
}

void
reset_timer(struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    timerUi->hours = 25;
    timerUi->seconds = 0;
    gtk_label_set_text(timerUi->label, "25:00");
}

gboolean
run_timer(struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    char formattedTime[6];
    char formattedSeconds[3];

    if (timerUi->seconds == 0)
        timerUi->seconds = 59;
    else
        timerUi->seconds = timerUi->seconds - 1;

    if (timerUi->seconds == 59)
        timerUi->hours = timerUi->hours - 1;

    if (timerUi->seconds < 10 && timerUi->seconds >= 0)
        snprintf(formattedSeconds, 3, "0%d", timerUi->seconds);
    else
        snprintf(formattedSeconds, 3, "%d", timerUi->seconds);

    snprintf(formattedTime, 6, "%d:%s", timerUi->hours, formattedSeconds);

    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(timerUi->label), formattedTime);

    return true;
}
```

### **src/features/timer.h**

```
#ifndef TIMER_H_INCLUDED
#define TIMER_H_INCLUDED

void        init_timer  (GtkBuilder *builder,
                        struct TimerUI *timerUi);

void        reset_timer (struct TimerUI*);

gboolean    run_timer   (struct TimerUI*);

#endif // TIMER_H_INCLUDED
```

### **src/frontend/frontend.c**

```
#include "frontend.h"
#include "../structures.h"

bool
init_view(GtkBuilder *builder)
{
    GError *error = NULL;

    // tricky way to make it work once installed but also if you compile manually
    if (gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "/usr/local/share/main/view.glade", &error) == 0) {
        if (gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "src/frontend/view.glade", &error) == 0) {
            g_warning("%s", error->message);
            g_clear_error(&error);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool
init_style(struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    GtkStyleContext *context;
    GtkCssProvider *provider;
    GError *error = NULL;

    context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(GTK_WIDGET(timerUi->label));
    provider = gtk_css_provider_new();

    // tricky way to make it work once installed but also if you compile manually
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(provider, "/usr/local/share/main/style.css", &error);
    if (error) {
        gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(provider, "/usr/local/share/main/style.css", &error);
        if (error) {
            g_warning("%s", error->message);
            g_clear_error(&error);
            return false;
        }
    }

    gtk_style_context_add_provider(context, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

    return true;
}
```

### **src/frontend/frontend.h**

```
#ifndef FRONTEND_H_INCLUDED
#define FRONTEND_H_INCLUDED

bool    init_view   (GtkBuilder *builder);

bool    init_style  (struct TimerUI *timerUi);

#endif // FRONTEND_H_INCLUDED
```

### **src/signals/options.c**

```
#include "options.h"
#include "../structures.h"

void stick_checkbox_signal(GtkToggleButton *checkBox, struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    bool isActive = gtk_toggle_button_get_active(checkBox);

    gtk_window_set_keep_above(timerUi->window, isActive);
}
```

### **src/signals/options.h**

```
#ifndef OPTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define OPTIONS_H_INCLUDED

void    stick_checkbox_signal   (GtkToggleButton*,
                                 struct TimerUI*);

#endif // OPTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

### **src/signals/timer_buttons.c**

```
#include "timer_buttons.h"
#include "../structures.h"
#include "../features/timer.h"

void
start_signal(GtkWidget *widget,
             struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    if (timerUi->timerReference != 0)
        return;

    timerUi->timerReference = g_timeout_add(1000, G_SOURCE_FUNC(run_timer), timerUi);
}

void
pause_signal(GtkWidget *widget,
             struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    if (timerUi->timerReference != 0)
        g_source_remove(timerUi->timerReference);

    timerUi->timerReference = 0;
}

void
reset_signal(GtkWidget *widget,
             struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    if (timerUi->timerReference != 0)
        g_source_remove(timerUi->timerReference);

    timerUi->timerReference = 0;

    reset_timer(timerUi);
}
```

### **src/signals/timer_buttons.h**

```
#ifndef TIMER_BUTTONS_H_INCLUDED
#define TIMER_BUTTONS_H_INCLUDED

void    start_signal    (GtkWidget*,
                         struct TimerUI*);

void    pause_signal   (GtkWidget*,
                        struct TimerUI*);

void    reset_signal    (GtkWidget*,
                         struct TimerUI*);

#endif // TIMER_BUTTONS_H_INCLUDED
```

### **src/frontend/view.glade**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="margin_left">3</property>
        <property name="margin_right">3</property>
        <property name="margin_top">3</property>
        <property name="margin_bottom">3</property>
        <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="bottomButtonReset">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Reset</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="margin_left">6</property>
            <property name="margin_right">6</property>
            <property name="margin_top">6</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">6</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="reset_signal" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">3</property>
            <property name="top_attach">12</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="bottomButtonPause">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Pause</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="margin_left">6</property>
            <property name="margin_right">6</property>
            <property name="margin_top">6</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">6</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="pause_signal" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">12</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="bottomButtonStart">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Start</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="margin_left">6</property>
            <property name="margin_right">6</property>
            <property name="margin_top">6</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">6</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="start_signal" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">2</property>
            <property name="top_attach">9</property>
            <property name="height">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkCheckButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Stick on screen</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">False</property>
            <property name="margin_left">6</property>
            <property name="margin_right">6</property>
            <property name="margin_top">6</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">6</property>
            <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
            <signal name="toggled" handler="stick_checkbox_signal" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">14</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="timer">
            <property name="name">timer-text</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_left">6</property>
            <property name="margin_right">6</property>
            <property name="margin_top">6</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">6</property>
            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">3</property>
            <property name="height">7</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

### **src/frontend/style.css**

```
#timer-text {
  font: 60px "Comic Sans";
}
```

## **Compile**

I compile the program on Ubuntu 20.04.1 using:

```
gcc-9 `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o main main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -rdynamic -g -Wall
```

### **Question**

Outside of the overall design of that C program, am I missing anything about security or performance? I’m not doing any memory management really, I wonder if I should (or maybe I misunderstand what it means). Basically, I wonder if I am missing things you need to do in C since I usually code with high-level programming languages.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. You will get a better code review if you include the complete files you want reviewed. Right now your code is missing at least the header file include statements.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That should be all the complete files now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Reconsider the directory structure

I generally prefer a flat data structure for programs as small and simple as this one.  That is, I'd put all of the code in `src` including `main.c`.  This makes maintenance a bit easier because we no longer need to include the directory structure in every single source file that uses an `#include`.  For more complex projects where I do use different directories, I tend to tell the compiler where to find the `#include` files rather than having that information hardcoded in each file.  That way, I have a single place (e.g. a `Makefile` or a `CMakeLists.txt` file) that stores the hierarchy.

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The code uses `bool` in several places but doesn't `#include <stdbool.h>`.  Also, a number of the include files are missing items.  For instance, the `timer.h` file is missing these:

```
#include "structures.h"
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

### Don't hardcode file names

Generally, it's not a good idea to hardcode a file name in software, and generally especially bad if it's an absolute file name (as contrasted with one with a relative path).  Instead, it would be better to allow the user of the program to specify the name, as with a command line parameter or a configuration file.

### Only `#include` header files

The `main.c` code incorrectly includes other `.c` files. What it should do instead is *only* include the `.h` files (the interface files).  Each `.c` file is converted into an object file `.o` and then they are linked into a single excutable.  I use `CMake` typically, so one way to write a `CMakeLists.txt` file for the top level of this project is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(pomodoro)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Then within the `src` directory, another `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})
add_executable(pomodoro  "timer_buttons.c" "options.c" "frontend.c" "timer.c" "main.c")
target_link_libraries(pomodoro ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

### Avoid duplicating contants

The code currently includes this function:

```
void
reset_timer(struct TimerUI *timerUi)
{
    timerUi->hours = 25;
    timerUi->seconds = 0;
    gtk_label_set_text(timerUi->label, "25:00");
}
```

If I wanted to change this to be, for example, a 15 minute timer, I'd have to make that change twice.  What I'd suggest instead is to create a function to format the string and then call it from here and also from within `run_timer`.  Even better, make it configurable by the user.  Also, that should clearly be `minutes` and not `hours`!

### Simplify formatting

The code currently has this for formatting the timer string:

```
char formattedTime[6];
char formattedSeconds[3];

if (timerUi->seconds < 10 && timerUi->seconds >= 0)
    snprintf(formattedSeconds, 3, "0%d", timerUi->seconds);
else
    snprintf(formattedSeconds, 3, "%d", timerUi->seconds);

snprintf(formattedTime, 6, "%d:%s", timerUi->hours, formattedSeconds);
```

That's much more complex than needed:

```
char formattedTime[6];
snprintf(formattedTime, 6, "%d:%2.2d", timerUi->minutes, timerUi->seconds);
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(timerUi->label), formattedTime);
```

In keeping with the previous suggestion, I'd factor it out like this:

```
static void 
set_timer_string(struct TimerUI *timerUi) 
{
#define TIMESTRINGLEN 6
    char formattedTime[TIMESTRINGLEN];
    snprintf(formattedTime, TIMESTRINGLEN, "%d:%2.2d", timerUi->minutes, timerUi->seconds);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(timerUi->label), formattedTime);
}
```

### Think of the user

If `style.css` fails to load or the `view.glade` file has an error in it, the user is given a rather cryptic error message and then the program abruptly halts.  It would be better to gracefully capture these and report useful error messages.

It's also a bit confusing that when the timer expires it shows "-1:59" and keeps going.  I'd have expected that it stops, or turns red or something to indicated that it has expired.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, you made very good points. I really lack time and I have moved to another project so I didn't take everything. I have implemented the "Avoid duplicating contants" and "Make sure you have all required #includes" so far and also fixed the negative timer bug. I'm not sure if we're allowed to share links but I have released the code https://github.com/lalande21185/pomodoro-timer.